# python argparse doesn't take string option start with "--"

Tags: python, argparse

I simplifying my problem here. I need to do this:

```
python test.py --arg1 '--no-route53'
```

I added the parser like this:

```
parser.add_argument("--arg1", nargs="?", type=str, help="option")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I wanted to get the '--no-route53' as a whole string and use it later in my script. But I keep getting this error:

```
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-route53
```

How can I work around it?

UPDATE1: if i give extra space after '--no-route53', like this and it worked:

```
python test.py --arg1 '--no-route53 '
```

Comment: Use equal symbol before argument value `python test.py --arg1='--no-route53'`

Comment: That string looks like an option flag. In argparse that interpretation has priority over treating it as the argument of the previous optional.  The shell does not preserve the extra layer of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue a while ago. I ended up pre-parsing the `sys.argv`list:

```
def bug_workaround(argv):
    # arg needs to be prepended by space in order to not be interpreted as
    # an option
    add_space = False
    args = []
    for arg in argv[1:]: # Skip argv[0] as that should not be passed to parse_args
        if add_space:
            arg = " " + arg
        add_space = True if arg == "--args" else False
        args.append(arg)

    return args


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My progrm.')
.
.
.
parser.add_argument('--args', type=str,
                    help='Extra args (in "quotes")')

args = parser.parse_args(bug_workaround(sys.argv))
# Prune added whitespace (for bug workaround)
if args.args:
    args.args = args.args[1:]
```

Comment: The easiest way I see is to do add "=" to it: python3 test.py --arg1='--no-route53'

Comment: Yes, but that requires the user to be aware of this. And that is not always the case.